# Why does Markdown in Jupyter Notebook represent these Horizontal Rules differently with the same input?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

In my Juptyter notebook I have many horizontal rules (generated in markdown cells) to break up the blocks of code, to create the horizontal rule I am using 3 underscores "___". For some reason, which I cannot figure out, the line sometimes appears as dark grey and sometimes as light grey.

In the screenshots below you can see the same "___" produces two differently colour lines.

Does anyone know the reason? Ideally i'd like them all to be the darker grey

[image: markdown code I am entering]

[image: different coloured lines produced]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What exact versions are you using?

Comment: Hi, i'm running version 5.4.0 of Jupyter Notebooks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the horizontal line color flip-flops each time you use it.

So the first line will be black, the second line will be gray, the third line will be black, etc.

Since I am using the horizontal line as a separator, I put the horizontal line before and after each section.